# Firebase addListenerForSingleValueEvent datasnapshot returning null

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I try to make a login activity using Firebase realtime database.

My database is filled as shown bellow when signing up:

[image: screenshot of the database structure]

Upon sign-in I want to initialize a public static User so that I can retrieve it in my main activity and update UI accordingly but the dataSnapshop of the ValueEventListener returns null.

Here is the code of my addListenerForSingleValueEvent :

```
currentUserReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        currentUserUsername = dataSnapshot.child("/username").getValue(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        currentUserUsername = "ERROR";
    }

});

// Get every information into a User class
MainActivity.CURRENT_USER_SESSION = new User(
        currentUserUsername,
        user.getEmail(),
        user.getUid()
);
```

Anyone has an idea to help me. Or any workaround or advice to do it better?

Edit: below is the initialization of the currenUserReference

```
currentUserReference = database.getReference("users/" + user.getUid());
```

the database is initialized in onCreate like that:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

the "user" from which I get the Uid is the FirebaseUser that is returned by firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser after checking if the signInWithEmailAndPassword.addOnCompleteListener was successful.

and after the addListenerForSingleValueEvent I added a Log.d that is writtent as follows:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Value of variable: " + currentUserUsername);
```

I expect the currentUserUsername to have the value of "username" in the databased assigned, but instead, I get:

> LoginActivity: Value of variable: null

Edit2: While debugging, I realized that when the debugger reaches the .addListenerForSingleValueEvent and I press F8, it completely skips this method. So, as someone said in the comment, the datasnapshot is probably not null, it's never accessed. But I still don't get why.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code of how you initialize `currentUserReference`.

Comment: Also note: the `dataSnapshot` that is passed to `onDataChange` will **never** be null. What exactly doesn't work. It's often easiest to see if you include som` Log.d()` statements that don't produce the output you expect.

Comment: Try it like this   ` currentUserUsername = (String) dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue();`

Comment: @Black4Guy it does not work, unfortunately. I edited with more information that might help. Should I edit the title since Frank told me that it was not possible that datasnapshot returns null and I confirmed that it was not actually my problem with debugging ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class) doesn't return null, when you exit onDataChange
your currentUserUsername is reinitialised.

So to pass the value to the next activity you need to:

```
currentUserReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            currentUserUsername = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            // Get every information into a User class
            MainActivity.CURRENT_USER_SESSION = new User(
                    currentUserUsername,
                    user.getEmail(),
                    user.getUid()
            );
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```